# how to get query parameter in action2 in sails

Tags: rest, http, sails.js, restful-url

I dont know how to set up route according to REST for the search request url like this

```
localhost:1337/system?id=10
```

After that, how can we get parameter from the above request in action 2 like this

> action2(inputs,exits)

I want to follow best practice for web api in sails. Please hint me to solve and recommend any handy documents.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For the Actions2 format, you'd use `inputs.id`, after properly defining the inputs, of course. For more information, consult the [documentation on Actions and Controllers](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers). This would need more finishing, but it gets your input and a function. You'd want to add in your exits, and some real logic, of course, and probably some decent descriptions.

```
module.exports = {
  inputs: {
    id: {
      type: 'number',
      required: true
    }
  },
  exits: {
    success: { ... },
    error: { ... }
  },
  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    var myId = inputs.id;
    return exits.success(myId);
  }
}
```