# Sails can I use Actions2 for GET request

Tags: sails.js

**The issue**

Can I use actions2 for GET requests with query params?

**Example**

https://path/filename?id=123&age=45

If this is the url in request, can I access each param as `input.id` and `input.age`?

I have not found many resources (basically only one) that show examples of this syntax being used for requests with query string parameters.

The github page redirects to a blog where they talk about the different methods one can apply actions2 syntax to, but does not directly display an example with a GET request
https://www.logisticinfotech.com/2018/sails-js-actions2-example-with-crud/.

The only online source that somewhat confirms this affirmation is the following:
[how to get query parameter in action2 in sails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50696569/how-to-get-query-parameter-in-action2-in-sails).

I am a newbie in SailsJS so feel free to ask me additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Actions2 for any API request; PUT, POST, GET, etc.

Here is an example from a repo I open sourced: https://github.com/neonexus/sails-react-bootstrap-webpack/blob/release/api/controllers/admin/get-me.js

While the example isn’t using GET params, it would use the “inputs” section just like with a PUT.